# Testing if binary symlink is found with GNU make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have a GNU `makefile` that looks something like this:

```
SOME_BINARY := $(shell `which some-binary` --help 2> /dev/null)

all: test_if_some_binary_exists

test_if_some_binary_exists:
ifdef SOME_BINARY
    @echo "some-binary found!"
else
    @$(error 'some-binary' not found!)
endif
```

Let's say I already have a binary called `some-binary`, which takes the option `--help` and writes a help message to standard error:

```
$ some-binary --help 
Some-Binary v1.2.3 (c) 2015 Foo Bar Baz
...
```

However, it is really a symbolic link to a file located elsewhere on the file system:

```
$ ls -l `which some-binary`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 alexpreynolds  admin  34 Aug 18 15:01 /usr/local/bin/some-binary -> ../Cellar/some-binary/1.2.3/bin/some-binary
```

When I run `make all` or `make test_if_some_binary_exists`, then I get an error as if the binary does not exist (when in fact it does):

```
$ make test_if_some_binary_exists
makefile:9: *** 'some-binary' not found!.  Stop.
```

How do I correctly test for existence of a binary — potentially a symbolic link — within a GNU `makefile`?

Comment: Use `type -p` or `command -v` instead of `which`. They are shell built-ins and not external binaries so they perform better and are guaranteed to report what your shell is actually going to see/use. Why bother *calling* the found path? Why not just use the return value of `type -p`/`command -v` (or `which` as the confirmation). What does `SOME_BINARY` contain at that point?

Comment: Your binary sends its `--help` output to standard error? Where does standard error go in that `$(shell)` call?

Comment: It goes to `/dev/null`, but I should get an not found or other non-zero error if the binary does not exist in the first place. If the binary exists, then the command should exit with a 0 error code. Correct?

Comment: You aren't checking the exit code anywhere. And yes, you should get a not found error when it doesn't exist. That error will go to standard error also. So when, exactly, are you expecting to get any output sent to standard output such that `$(shell)` can capture it and make can store it into `SOME_BINARY`?

Comment: If I leave out `2> /dev/null`, the output goes to the standard output of the `make` process, instead of to `SOME_BINARY`. How should I correctly capture that output in a non-shell specific way, so that I can test if that variable is set?

Comment: `2>&1` but that misses the point. You probably **don't** want to be testing that `--help` works. You probably just want to be testing that `type -p`/`command -v` returns a path to the binary at all. Without inspecting the `--help` output (to make sure it is the binary you expect) you don't gain much from checking that `binary --help` works anyway.

Comment: Are those generic built-ins or specific to one shell? I am trying to avoid having to go with a specific shell or version of a shell just to test if a binary exists. I guess I'll try to figure out a different way, thanks.

Comment: POSIX specified. See [command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html) and [type](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html). Though `type -p` isn't POSIX. Like I said, just use the output of `command -v` as your indicator. If `command -v some-binary` returns a string then you have *something* available with that name. Either a binary, script, shell function or shell alias. You can further check that that outputs an absolute path if you want to avoid shell functions and aliases.